# Where to write Database and Business logic in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

As I am learning and working on Asp.Net MVC application, I want to know that what is the better place to write `Business Logic` and `Data Access logic` in `MVC`.

Where should I write DataAccess and Business Logic among three layers (`Model, View and Controller`) ??

Could anybody please tell me the correct way to write the code for this.

Scenario: I want to `retrieve all the employees where employee name like 'Mi%'` ( I have `SQL procedure to execute and retrieve the data.`)

PS: **Want to know that where I should create instance of Business Logic class and where I should create instance of Data Access layers class?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be sure and check out the [NerdDinner tutorial.](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm)

Comment: check out IoC pattern for creating BL and DAO objects, Steven Sanderson in his book Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework covers this topic pretty well or try googling "asp.net mvc ioc"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Business logic should be in the Model.

Data Access can either be its own later your Controllers call, or automated in an ORM that your Controller will call through repositories.

A walk-through covering this can be found in [Nerd Dinner](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-321793.html), look for the [free download section](http://content.wrox.com/wroxfiles/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v2.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Blu, Just want to know where where I should create instance of Business Logic class and where I should create instance of Data Access layers class ?

Comment: DAL classes are going to be created in the Controller.  If your BLL classes are a layer on top of your DAL then the Controller will create those instead, and the BLL will create the DAL components it needs.

Comment: @nunu: Don't think of business logic as "a business logic class" but instead as logic baked into your models.  Part 3 of the Nerd Dinner tutorial has some basic examples: http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part3.htm

Comment: The UI, BLL, DAL approach is not typically used in MVC in my experience.  Business logic is rolled into the Model, and the DAL is implemented in an ORM that is made accessible through repositories.  There is probably going to be a shift on your part in terms of architecture, and the pdf will help a lot.  To get you started you can use your BLL/DAL classes in your controllers and refactor as you learn more about MVC.

Comment: @blu In a well structured application you should be able to swap out MVC for WCF or any other UI/access strategy and the logic will all still be there. If you wrap logic into your view models/controllers you've violated this.

Comment: I agree with Ryan on this, a well structured webforms app should be easy to migrate to MVC provided that the Service/BLL/DA layers are separated out.

Comment: @Ryan "swap out MVC for WCF"?

Comment: @blu Not something you'd actually do, but say you have an MVC interface and you need to drop Silverlight in on a page. You should still be able to get to the application logic through WCF with Silverlight the same as if you were on an MVC page. This primarily applies to enterprise applications.

Comment: @Ryan I am still trying to understand the purpose of your comment and what it adds that my answer did not cover.  Also presumably you down voted my answer as well and am trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 10):

Business logic (BL) and data access (DAO) should be in separate layers. Models should only keep data and contain no logic. Controller should only receive data from view and send it to BL layer (or send from BL to view).
It's not a strict rules, but most recently used approach

Comment: Exactly! MVC != 3 tier development. MVC is the UI level only. Business logic and db access should go somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The view is where you put your interface code.

The Controller is the place that connects the view with the model.

The model stores business logic and possibly database access. (Some ORM Layer can be used aswell)

Answer (score 0):

You could skip the three tier thinking completely and go for another way of thinking;

User Acts; that sends Command or Event to Background Service. Background Service you can run in process, for starters. Background Service publishes events, again, in memory. You create multiple Views that subscribe the Event from the Background Service. Each View has a 'last seen' Event; it's an integer. Each Start it *reads* all later Events from the "global log".

Views are throw-away, because you have a global log of Event/Command from GUI and from Background Service, and they'll read up all missed events when you start, anyhow.

This is the equivalent of "do something and I expect to see that 'change' in this other view". You also have:

An Interaction is when you have a single or multiple Events from either GUI or Background Service and you let some actor, most likely a [Saga](http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/overview/saga.html), perform some action, possibly with compensations based on other Events, should the action fail.

Also, I can recommend browsing [this presentation](http://www.lowlevelmanager.com/2012/09/lambda-architecture.html)