# Dont we need DAL Layer In MVC3 architecture?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to write Database and Business logic in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679263/where-to-write-database-and-business-logic-in-mvc)

I have just started with MVC3 pattern. How do we do data access in MVC3? Do we make the 'MODEL' as Data Access Layer or Do we add another 'DAL' layer and call it from 'MODEL' Layer?

Comment: This has been asked many, many, many times over.

Comment: Question is do we need more flexibility in our application ?? Answer is yes !! There are lot of examples available as suggested by our contributes in this post , How ever its your idea where you want DAL in your system , I would like to separate my transactions with Db and application logic , so that if one of any two of them faces any up-gradation or if there are any changes it will not require to disturb both our DB or application , A layer ,an interface or abstract class between your DBContext class  and your application.

Answer (score 1):

Your model should be independent of data-access stuff, which will allow you to change your DAL strategy in the future.

You should be feeding the model from the DAL, but the model shouldn't know how it is being constructed, and certainly shouldn't have any database-specific code in it.

If you take the approach I suggest, look at AutoMapper - a very useful tool for mapping data between DAL and model classes.

Answer (score 0):

When I was working with my last MVC3 project, my understanding from the various samples (such as GeekDinner) was that the Entity Framework serves as the Data Access Layer.

Comment: You're right; modify my answer to reflect your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Your Model *can be* a directly mapped data access object, but don't necessarily have to be. They could just as well be proxies through to your backend DAL which is always going to be the better option depending on your requirements and longevity of the project.

The way I tend to handle it for larger projects is to have a separate namespace called `Project.Entities` which contains my Entity Framework data models. My `Project.Models` would contain models which use the Entities as a backing store for their data, and provide common methods (Where necessary) to manipulate that data. It may not be the best way to do it, but provides the most flexibility, and sticks to keeping data models separate from the backing store which allows more abstraction. For example, you can always switch out the underlying data layer to in-memory storage, another DAL than Entity Framework or whatever else.

For smaller/temporary/test projects, my Entity Framework data models will be straight in `Project.Models` and used directly as it's quicker and doesn't require so much thought.

Answer (score 0):

No, model is not data access. Model is a buch of classes to hold data, and it generally does not contain code other than, possibly, to verify the assigned values are permitted.

You access data from controllers. In which way you do that is completely up to you and MVC is not concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Model is your view model, not your domain model.

If you want to do DAL activity, I would tend to wrap it in repository/service that can be injected into your controllers.

This stops your controllers getting bloated and also allows you to mock your DAL layer for unit testing the controllers.